# Using GDAL to strip nodata in border regions only?

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to create a script that given a tiff file with islands of data (which can be disjoint) and black pixels of nodata, can generate polygons (or new tiffs) that only wrap around the islands of data. The issue I am facing is that my nodata value is automatically 0 (0 0 0 I think actually, or black), and some of my islands also contain the value 0 inside of them, what is the best way to accomplish this in gdal?

For example, if I run a command like:

`gdalwarp -srcnodata 0 -dstnodata 0 orig-ignore-black.tif black-nodata.tif`

my resulting tiff has pockets inside the data regions that have been stripped because they had a 0 value.

Comment: Alpha band could work better than nodata for you.

Comment: If you have vectors representing the valid data areas you could re-clip with gdalwarp and choose a more appropriate nodata value

Comment: @user30184, could you explain more?

Comment: Read for example https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/18764/setting-alpha-vs-nodata-color-and-numeric-data.html and https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masks.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running [`gdal_sieve.py`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html) to remove the zeros within your data islands; replacing them with nearby values. You will have to experiment with the parameters to get the result you want. The zero values in the resulting file become your nodata mask. You can then try stacking the mask and your original raster with `gdal_merge.py -separate`. Finally you can try gdal_translate. Pay close attention to the `-mask` and `-b` options in the [docs](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).